# How to iterate each element of an array over a given range in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, iteration

I have a function that outputs an integer based on a 9 x 1 array. I want to check the functions output for various array values, so ideally I would like to iterate each element of the array in the range (0,3). Is there a simpler way to do this than having 9 nested for loops?

Comment: Please provide a sample input/output along with what you have tried to solve your problem. See [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: the permutations are really big. This is a complex problem. 9 loops is the bruteforce way, but it may take too long, and you'd need to jump to multivariable optimization, such as GAs and others.

Comment: Your Question is not very clear. can you edit it and provide your code snippet? The problem you are saying do not seem humongous, but if the question is still unanswered then it might be interesting to look at it . :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have 3^9 arrangement. If you had a function that can attribute the numbers 1 to 3^9 to each combination, you could do a single loop.

```
for i=1:3^9
    current_array = arrangement_no(i);
    test_function(current_array);
end
```

To define this function, basically convert to base 3 each number, take the digits and add one. I'll give an example for an array of size 3 with entries in the range 0:2 (try this first if you can).

```
function current_array = arrangement_no(i)
current_array = zeros(1,3)
for j = 1:3
   current_array(end+1-j) = mod(i,3);
   i= floor(i/3);
end
end
```